# Unable to access a web service in AWS node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deployed a simple hello world web service (spring boot) in one of the AWS EC2 instances. I am able to do a curl to this web service from within the node and it works fine. However, I am not able to call this service from outside this node. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a issue with the security groups. Check if security groups attached to EC2 instance allows HTTP traffic.

Comment: Yes it does. Here is my security group inbound rule:
Type-HTTP
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 80
Source 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: @DeepakSrivathsan EC2 instance will have private and public ip address. Are you trying with Public ip address?